# WPF при публикации не вкладывает папку с картинками и файл

Tags: wpf, .net, visual-studio, clickonce

В проекте есть папка с картинками и файл базы данных SqlLite.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все файлы имеют свойство "Всегда копировать". Файл БД есть в сборки bin.  Папка с изображениями там отсутствует.

При публикации проекта "Установка с CD". Не файл БД, не папка Изображений не попадают в папку публикации.

Comment: Для копирования картинок можно каждой из них установить признак "всегда копировать".

Comment: Уже установлено но ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

1. Для всех нужных файлов выставить в свойствах "Действие при сборке" = "Содержание".
2. Открыть свойства проекта - "Публикация" - "Файлы приложения". Для нужных файлов установить в столбце "Состояние публикации" значение "Включить".