# Приложение запускается через Visual Studio но не запускается после публикации

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio, clickonce

Написал простенькое приложение для работы с таблицами, которое прекрасно работает при запуске через Visual Studio (плей). Но не хочет запускаться после публикации и установки (на этот же компьютер)

В чем может быть причина куда копать?

---

В коде я использую вот такую конструкцию для вызова картинок

```
try
{
    this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(appPath + "FONT.png");
}
catch (Exception){ throw; }

this.label2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
this.checkBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

try
{
    this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(appPath + "renault.png");
}
```

Ошибка

> Сигнатура проблемы: P1: Table explorer.exe P2: 1.0.0.0 P3: a86c6ece P4: System.Drawing P5: 4.7.3056.0 P6: 5a8e59fe P7: 321 P8: 14 P9: System.IO.FileNotFoundException P10

Исходники
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tcsu2xsbflc8hi/Table%20explorer.rar?dl=0

Comment: Копать, для начала, в сторону правил сайта, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . RAR-архив на dropbox и никакого описания, кроме "не хочет запускаться" - совсем плохо. Что касается самой проблемы, обычно после возникновения ошибки в журнале Windows создается событие, которое содержит подробную информацию о ней. Для публикации ClickOnce типичная ошибка - указание в манифесте Partial Trust, который не дает доступ к локальной файловой системе, и приводит к падению приложения на самых ранних этапах.

Comment: потому что больше никаких симптомов я не выявил, это моя первая программа на с# и первый проект на Visual Studio, проявите снисходительность... проект на winforms как указано в ключевых словах а не на WPF  я так понимаю partial trust к winfofms не относится

Comment: дополнительная информация: из папки debug приложение запускается, а из папки release - нет. Значит ли это что IDE при сборке пропускает какие то важные файлы?

Comment: из внешних ресурсов у меня две картинки, обе добавлены в папку с репозиторием, возможно их нужно как то прописать в файле ресурсов, но как и где и как правильно указать абсолютные пути к ним чтобы при развертывании все подзватывалось правильно?

Comment: А приложение часом собрано не как UWP?

Comment: Я не знаю...  а как это проверить? Писал приложение в VS2019 в качестве шаблона использовался: Приложение Windows Forms (NET)

Comment: Если картинки добавлены в проект как ресурсы, они вшиваются в exe-файл и ничего дополнительно делать не надо. Если картинки добавлены как обычные файлы, нужно их включить в публикуемые, как описано здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/938187/wpf-при-публикации-не-вкладывает-папку-с-картинками-и-файл/941815#941815

Comment: Сигнатура ошибки в логах винды
Сигнатура проблемы:
P1: Table explorer.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: a86c6ece
P4: System.Drawing
P5: 4.7.3056.0
P6: 5a8e59fe
P7: 321
P8: 14
P9: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
P10: 


Я так понимаю срабатывает исключение, не находит какой то файл, скорее всего картинку, сейчас попробую разобраться как их добавить чтобы они переносились правильно

Comment: Параметры безопасности ClickOnce одинаково применимы и к WPF, и к WinForms (в целом, публикация ClickOnce не привязана к фреймворкам). Если приложение требует доступа к локальным файлам, реестру и т.п., для него в свойствах проекта на вкладке "Безопасность" должно быть установлено "С полным доверием" ("Full trust")

Comment: подскажите как в конструкции тру\кэтч при кэтч вывести сообщение в логи\или прямо форму вызвать с тектом ошибки, чтобы понимать из какой части программы идет ислкючение

Comment: В коде я использую вот такую конструкцию для вызова картинок

            try
            {
                this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(appPath + "FONT.png");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            this.label2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            this.checkBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;


            try
            {
                this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(appPath + "renault.png");
            }

Comment: Самое простое - `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());`, где ex - переменная Exception. Если в файл - `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, ex.ToString());`, выбрав в качестве пути какую-либо папку, к которой есть доступ, например, "Мои документы".

Comment: Параметры безопасности ClickOnce были выставлены корректно и изначально, согласно вашим рекомендациям.

Comment: я не понимаю где нужно добавлять картинки в публикуемые, в вашем ответе есть пункт - 
Открыть свойства проекта - "Публикация" - "Файлы приложения". Для нужных файлов установить в столбце "Состояние публикации" значение "Включить".
Я нашел это окно но там нет нужных картинок ( картинки находятся по адресу \source\repos\Table explorer\bin\Debug) 

а как первый пункт сделать... не могу понять

Comment: Возможно, они у вас не добавлены в проект (просто скопировать в папку - мало). Правой кнопкой по проекту - Добавить - Существующий файл. После этого файл должен появиться в дереве проекта, и для него можно будет редактировать свойства.

Comment: Ура ура ура!!! Получилось, значицо так

1. Картинки лучше добавлять картинки через через свойства формы, тогда все пропишется куда следует автоматически,
2. Как их добавлять программно через код пока не умею
3. Потом вам надо найти добавленные файлы через обозреватель VS и в их свойствах указать "Действие при сборке" = "Содержание". (как правильно написал MSDN.WhiteKnight)
4. после этого вы заходите в свойства проекта - "Публикация" - "Файлы приложения". Для нужных файлов установить в столбце "Состояние публикации" значение "Включить". (хотя вообще должно уже быть проставлено)

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight вы можете сделать ПОСТ, я помечю его как ответ, однако остался еще один суб-вопрос, как теперь из папки Release сделать инсталлятор, а и после всего этого вам надо перестроить сборку Release. Чтобы применить все изменения.

Comment: "*еще один суб-вопрос, как теперь из папки Release сделать инсталлятор*" - вроде просто переключиться на конфигурацию Release, повторить в ней все изменения в свойствах проекта, а затем нажать на публикацию еще раз. Должно сработать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если приложение использует внешние файлы изображений, просто добавить их в папку Debug - недостаточно. Чтобы они были включены в дистрибутив при публикации, необходимо пометить их как публикуемые:

1. Добавить файлы в проект (Правой кнопкой по проекту - "Добавить" - "Существующий файл")
2. Выставить в свойствах файлов "Действие при сборке" = "Содержание".
3. Открыть свойства проекта - "Публикация" - "Файлы приложения". Для нужных файлов установить в столбце "Состояние публикации" значение "Включить".

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ninrwp 

Переключился на конфигурацию Release ( теперь окно пуска выглядит так http://prntscr.com/ninse3)

уточните пожалуйста, что вы имеете ввиду под 'повторить в ней все изменения в свойствах проекта'

Comment: @JulianDelCampo Если вы вносили в свойства проекта какие-то изменения в Debug, например, пометили файлы как публикуемые, то в Release их, возможно, нужно будет повторить заново, так как некоторые свойства проекта настраиваются независимо в каждой конфигурации. Если этой проблемы у вас нет, то ничего дополнительно делать не нужно, просто нажмите на публикацию.